# JQuery disables all hyperlinks

Tags: jquery

I am puzzled why adding JQuery 1.1.10 disables all the links on my web page.

In my script I have methods like this:

```
btnnextslide.click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
```

... but they are only bound to some specific links. However it appears that ALL links in the page gets disabled. Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that there's a `preventDefault()` or `return false` in a function bound to all links or a common ancestor element such as `body`. But the only way we can find out for sure is by seeing your code!

Answer (score 1):

by `e.preventDefault();` it stop their default behaviour

reference **[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

Comment: I think the issue is that the poster can't work out why it's applying to all links instead of just the ones it should be bound to.